# Stored procedure with multiple selects - interaction with client tool?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, multiple-select

Suppose I have a stored procedure as follows:

```
create procedure p_x
as
begin
   select 'a','b','c'
   select 'c','d','e'
   select 'e','f','g'
end
go
```

This is of course not the real code, but it illustrates enough to be able to ask my questions.

I'm looking for the best performance and the best practices to deal with it.

1. How will the client tool (eg Informatica Data Quality) calling this procedure react?

   - Will it receive 3 separate results, just the last query result or all results at once?
   - Will each separate query be send to the client directly (and will the procedure halt till completed)? or is this done after the procedure finished?
   - Is it good practice to work this way? I was looking for the exchange of an OUTPUT table type parameter, but this doesn't seem possible if I'm correct (based on other stories)(just as input)
   - Is there a performance impact in this way? And if so what is the way to do this as efficient as possible (e.g. to just send one result back to the client)

Comment: In many SQL Server tools the first query will be processed and unless you take a lot of action the rest of the queries will be ignored. This is an issue for Informatica. All the data will be sent over the wire - what Informatica does is what you need to find out. You probably should go to a Informatica forum.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better served by posting your question to the Informatica forums. They should be able to answer your questions precisely and accurately. But I'll give it a go.

*How will the tool react?* Don't know, but often tools that support using stored procedures as a datasource will assume and will consume a single (and the first) resultset. Any others will be ignored. Go ask in their forums.

*Will it receive 3 ...?* Roughly the same question and answer as the first.

*Will each separate query ...?* Your procedure produces three resultsets. How the client consumes them is, again, something you should ask in their forums. The procedure itself will not "halt" waiting for the client to do anything.

*Is it good practice...?* Not in my opinion. Nor is posting a complete nonsense procedure a useful tool for discussing the pros/cons of this approach. Can it be a useful thing to do? Likely. But it is not often done IME. In addition, you are dealing with a tool with which  you are not familiar. The simpler you keep things the better you are off in the long run regardless of your tools.

A procedure is a unit of work and should do one "thing". If it produces multiple resultsets, one can argue that it ceases to do a single thing since, logically, each resultset represents a set of different (even if related) things. And typically one would expect to see some relationship among the resultsets. If there are no relationships, then the resultsets are obviously different things which violates the idea of a procedure. You might want to review the topic of coupling and cohesion. But I think I see a bigger issue - which I'll address with the next item.

Is there a performance impact ...? This can't really be answered. Performance is always, ALWAYS specific to a particular situation (query, schema, etc). Based on that last sentence, I think you have not made the adjustment to thinking in terms of sets - something that is critical to writing efficient sql. Rather, I'll guess that you are thinking in terms of a loop which includes a select statement and each iteration will produce a set of (perhaps 1 but who knows) rows. If you think you have the "option" to produce just one resultset of  3 rows vs. 3 resultsets of 1 row, then you are most likely stuck in [RBAR](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar-row-by-agonizing-row/) land. Regardless, this can't really be answered. It is also a question for the Informatica people.